# Setting up a Tor bridge?

Tags: relays, bridge

I have a Windows server I hardly use, and I decided that I wanted to use it to run a Tor bridge.  I've been trying all morning to figure out how to set it up to no avail.  Most of the tutorials I've found online want me to install the Tor Vidalia Bridge Bundle, but Tor seems to no longer distribute that on their official site.  The only things available are the browser bundle and the expert bundle.  The expert bundle only contains tor.exe, which when run through the command line produces no output.

How can I set up my server to run a Tor bridge?  Am I missing some obvious article on their site that provides a step-by-step guide?  Am I failing to Google properly?

Comment: They "[stopped shipping](https://twitter.com/torproject/status/213002456190304257)" it due to security concerns and seem to focus on the TorBrowser. I'm also looking for advice on how to run a relay on Win7 now.